# Mean Stack :I want to send array of id and want to find data against each id

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

So what I am trying to do is I have Array Of UserId and I am sending this Array in req body to nodejs api.
Now a list of problems i am facing

1 Dont know how to get and console the request body of array of ids.
2 Once I get and console this array. How I use loop to find the data of User against Each Id.

Here is my code.

form service.ts

```
  GetUnSuspensionBody(ArrayofUserId){
     return this._HttpClient.get(GetUnSuspensionBodyRequestUrl ,ArrayofUserId);
   }
```

in nodejs Api

```
 Router.get('/UnSuspensionBodyRequest', (req, res) => {

     //Want to Get the req.body(ofArrays) then console it
     //Then Use that Array of id's i want to loop through all the collection and get user data 
 against each id

 })
```

Please Guys Help Me. Thanks in Advance.

```
 So for Single id this the code inculding schemas and its working perfectly

 So What i am doing is there are two schemas.

  1
  const mongoose = require('mongoose');
  const UserUnSuspensionMessageSchema=mongoose.Schema({
 
      UserId:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      Message:String


  })

  module.exports=mongoose.model('UserUnSuspensionMessageCluster', 
  UserUnSuspensionMessageSchema);

  2
  const UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({
      Name: { type: String, required: true, unique:true},
      Email: { type: String, required: true, unique:true},
      Mobile: { type: Number, required: true },
      Password: { type: String, required: true },
      ImageUrl: { type: String },
      ImageName: { type: String },
      ImageMimeType: { type: String },
      Address: { type: String, require: true },
      CreatedDate: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
      SaltString:{type:String},
      Status:{type:Number, default:1}
  })
 So and this is my Api (for single id) which running perfectly

  Router.get('/UnSuspensionBodyRequest:id', (req, res) => {
      const UserId = req.params.id;
      let TotalDocuments;
      UserUnSuspensionMessage.countDocuments({}, function (err, count) {
          TotalDocuments = count
      });
      UserUnSuspensionMessage.findOne({ UserId: UserId })
          .then(UnSuspendedUserData => {
              UserCluster.find(UnSuspendedUserData.UserId)
                  .then(UserData => {
                       res.json({
                          TotalSandBox: TotalDocuments,
                          SandBoxId: UnSuspendedUserData._id,
                          SandBoxMessage: UnSuspendedUserData.Message,
                          UserName: UserData,
                          Result: "Found",
                          Data: true
                      })
                  })
          })
          .catch(err => { res.json(err.message) });
  })
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> Problems with your methods:

Your way of making the request is wrong in terms of what you are trying to achieve.

The `GET` method does not have a request body.

> To answer your question:
> Angular Frontend:

```js
 // Data to be sent to the backend
 const requestData = {
       data: [id1,id2,id3]
    }
 GetUnSuspensionBody(ArrayofUserId){
     return this._HttpClient.post(GetUnSuspensionBodyRequestUrl ,requestData);
   }
```

Node.js Backend:
Include bodyparser in your main file:

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json()); // for parsing application/json
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); // for parsing application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

Router:

```js
 router.post('/UnSuspensionBodyRequest', async (req, res) => {
   // Extract the the array of ids from the request body
    const {data} = req.body
   // Log your ids here
   console.log(data)
  
  // With MongoDB you have the $in operator to use an array as the search creteria
 // Plus putting DB request in a loop is a really bad practice regardless which DB you are using
  const bdResult = await db.collection.find({_id:{ $in: recipients, }})

  // Log the result from the query here
  console.log(dbResult)

 })
```

## Final Notes:

1. [Read the StackOverFlow Guideline](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before asking questions
2. [Understand the basic autonomy of HTTP requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods)
3. Read the documentations of the technologies that you are using

Comment: Let me try your Code hint. And bro I have edited my question

Comment: Bro its says undefined

Comment: You are being vague again what says what is undefined and where.

Comment: bro I am trying to upload the image. bro can i have you hangouts where i can show you the problem live. Please it really help me out

Comment: I know i am being vauge but if you have 3 minutes ill show you live and you will understand my probelm

Comment: https://ibb.co/bPT44TH

Comment: Now you are trying to upload an image? That's totally different from the questions you asked here. Please open another question for this topic and focus on solving your existing problems here. Read the guideline on how to ask a question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Bro in the question I have Mentioned Mean Stack.

Comment: My question is simple let me explain again. I want to get the data on the base of ArrayOfIds. and once these ids reached my api first i check them by console.log then use these id i can get all the user data.

Comment: But when i console my array of id its says undefined as i have followed your code. 
please see the link https://ibb.co/bPT44TH

Comment: That is how I am sending my request from my service.ts component
Please see the link 
https://ibb.co/WVB5w7G

Comment: request data need a property for express to access it. It is in the answer above. ` const requestData = {
       data: [id1,id2,id3]
    }` Now replace `[id1,id,i2,]` with `arrayofUserId`. Without the data, property express will not know what's `req.body.data` because you are accessing an object using a property that does not exist.

Comment: GetUnSuspensionBody(ArrayofUserId){
    //The ArrayofUserId has the id's
    console.log(ArrayofUserId);
    const requestData:any = {data:ArrayofUserId}
    return this._HttpClient.get(GetUnSuspensionBodyRequestUrl ,requestData);
  }

Backend

Router.get('/UnSuspensionBodyRequest', (req, res) => {
    
    const {data}=req.body
    console.log(data);


still undefined as i am using the key

Comment: Because for POST requests you need the body-parser library. Did you have that? It's a very basic step.

Comment: Yes bro I have all the modules required to run my application. Well if you come live for 5 minutes i think we could solve the problem. because lots of errors are coming.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227204/discussion-between-aviv-lo-and-work-space).